# Why is $ r \propto v$ in the equation $r=\frac{mv}{qB}$?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields

For a charged particle in a magnetic field,
$qvB=m\frac{v^2}{r}$ and hence $r=\frac{mv}{qB}$.

In confirming that this result is consistent with Newton's laws, my notes say

> A fast moving charged particle would travel further (in the direction of motion) than a slow moving charge, for the same perpendicular acceleration, leading to the same result as above, a larger radius of curvature.

Hence explaining why $r \propto v$.

My question is, if $v$ increases, doesn't the centripetal force increase as $F = qvB$? So their perpendicular acceleration increases. I do not understand what my notes mean by same perpendicular acceleration.

Comment: This is a bad explanation and you are right to dislike it. The real point is that the centripetal force increases with v, just not enough to compensate for the increased distance the particle travels forward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In problems such as this, you can use the math to check if your conclusions are true or not:

For the scenario you described involving a moving charge in a magnetic field,

$$ F= ma = qvb$$

Now since you wrote $ r = mv/qB$, rewrite this as $v = qBr/m$ and substitute this back to the equation $F = ma$ to get:

$$ a = (qB/m)^2r $$
which upon rearranging:

$$ r/a = (m/qB)^2$$

What we see here is that $r/a$ is a constant if the electron/charge that moves in this magnetic field with strength $B$.

So for the ratio to be constant, any increase in $a$ (the centripetal acceleration) will be compensated by an increase in $r$ (the radius of curvature).

And now since $r \propto v$ as you indicated, then $v/a$ too has the same constant ratio.

Answer (score 1):

Perpendicular acceleration is the acceleration towards the center - in the direction of the centripetal force. Remember for circular motion, centripetal force is given by $F = mv^2/r = ma$, or $a = v^2/r$. For the same $a$, a larger $v$ therefore implies a larger $r$.

Comment: But why would $a$ be the same? $a = F/m=qvB/m$ and as $v$ increases, doesn't $a$ also increase?

Comment: @Freddie it's because the notes say $a$ stays the same: *for the same perpendicular acceleration*. $a = qvB/m$ does give the impression that as $v$ increases so does $a$, but $a = v^2/r$, and $r$ is not necessarily constant.

Answer (score 1):

I think the deciding factor is that the force $qvb$ is "linear" with the velocity $v$.

Let us say that the charge is moving with some velocity $v$ in uniform magnetic field and perpendicular to the direction of the magnetic field, then the force is $qvb$ and we know that the charge moves on a circle which can't be completed without a centripetal force. *So the magnetic force serves as the center seeking force here*.

Now *if you double the velocity then in order to move on the same circle the center seeking force must rise to four times it's initial value but as I said earlier the force $qvb$ is linear with $v$, thus you can only get twice the value of the initial force*.

So indeed increasing the velocity increases the force but not much to restrict the particle on the same trajectory. And thus the radius increases.